# odd Javascript setTimeout behaviour

Tags: javascript

The following code waits 2 seconds then prints some hello worlds.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myTimedFunction()">

<script>
    function myTimedFunction() {
        setTimeout(function() { document.write("hello world");document.write(" hello world2");runMe();}, 2000); 
    }
    function runMe(){document.write(" hello world3");}
</script>
<br>
<p>This text will disappear when the script runs</p>

</body>
</html>
```

like it says in the p tag the text disapears after the script has run. Furthermore, the webpage shows "Connecting..." with a loading symbol next to it when the script runs; this goes away when I hit escape. Why does the text disappear? Why is the javascript not stopping until I hit escape, missing semicolon? I am using firefox, in chrome the "Connecting..." never comes up, but the text still vanishes.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

If the current document is still “open”, i.e. it’s still being parsed, `document.write` will insert its argument string at the current position in the document. When the page has finished parsing, though, as it is after `onload` (and a two-second timeout), it’s closed; `document.write` will reopen it, which has the effect of removing all current content.

Create a text node and append it to `<body>` instead!

```
function myTimedFunction() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var textNode = document.createTextNode('hello world');

        document.body.appendChild(textNode);
    }, 2000); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem doesn't have anything to do with setTimeout. This usually happens when using document.write.

Simply replace your document.write with something like:

```
document.querySelector('body>p').innerHTML += 'hello world';
```

If you look it up, you will see that document.write is considered a bad practice, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) out for reasons but in your case the main reason is:

> document.write executed after the page has finished loading will overwrite the page, or write a new page, or not work

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myTimedFunction()">


<br>
<p>This text will disappear when the script runs</p>

</body>
</html>

<script>
    function myTimedFunction() {
       setTimeout(function() { document.write(document.body.innerHTML+"hello world");document.write(" hello world2");runMe();}, 2000); 
    }
    function runMe(){document.write(" hello world3");}
</script>
```